# What does the Archon Battle Frenzy buff do?

Tags: xcom-2

The Archon is the flying enemy unit that replaces the old Floaters from *XCOM: Enemy Unknown/Within*. When you attack and hit the Archon, it gains some kind of buff called Battle Frenzy.

What does Battle Frenzy do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Battle Frenzy grants the injured Archon:

- +1 action point
- Preference to use melee attack (7 damage)

Comment: How do you find these things out, when the new game has no F1 key to view enemy abilities?

Comment: @SimonW XCOM2 is a very modable game which has quite a lot of game mechanics in human-readable .ini files. I haven't found the one which lists information about unit abilities, though. But you could ask about that as a new question if you like.

Comment: So Archons can't actually melee you unless you've recently injured them first? Good to know!

Comment: @DarthPizza I would suggest not attacking an Archon unless you have your squad in the right position so you can take him out as quickly as possible.  A 7 damage melee is nothing to laugh at

Comment: Are you sure about the melee attack? I just saw a completely uninjured archon perform one. Maybe it just unlocks a *stronger* one?

Comment: @skully so you mean it *loses* its ranged attack?

Comment: @Philipp Fixed, since my experience with an Archon had them down right before they could even start their turns, the one time it triggered battle frenzy it switched from ranged to melee and nicked one of my grenadiers